# R mediation packge: Multiple-trial binomial mediator works when fit with Lumley's survey package, but not with glm. What's wrong?

Tags: r, statistics, survey, weighted

I'm running two mediations on the same data, once using prior (sampling) weights when fitting the models (through Lumley's `survey` package), and once without those prior weights (just using the `glm()` function). My outcome is binary. My mediator is a proportion out of 3, so I also pass 3 as the weights argument (or rather, the name of a column that is equal to 3 for every subject). When using the models fit with `survey:svyglm()` inside `mediation::mediate()`, there is no issue; however, when using the `glm()` models, `mediate()` complains that "weights on outcome and mediator models not identical".

EXAMPLE 1: Works for models with with `survey` package:

```
set.seed(3452393)

library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(mediation)

n <- 100

dat <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  y_binary = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  m_binomial = sample(c(0,1/3,2/3,3/3), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)),
  m_binomial_max = 3,
  m_binary = ifelse(m_binomial == 1, 1, 0),
  pred_normal = rnorm(n = n),
  weight = rnorm(n = n, mean = 15),
  weight_rep1 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep3 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep4 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep5 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight)
)

dat_design <- dat |> 
  srvyr::as_survey_rep(
    repweights = dplyr::contains("_rep"),
    weights = weight,
    combined_weights = TRUE
  )

# weighted models 

model_y_weighted <- survey::svyglm(
  formula = y_binary ~ m_binomial + pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design, 
  family = "binomial"
)

model_m_weighted <- survey::svyglm(
  formula = m_binomial ~ pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design, 
  family = "binomial",
  weights = m_binomial_max
)

mediation_weighted <- mediation::mediate(
  model.m = model_m_weighted,
  model.y = model_y_weighted,
  treat = "pred_normal",
  mediator = "m_binomial",
  sims = 50
)

# warning:
# weights taken as sampling weights, not total number of trials
```

EXAMPLE 2: Doesn't work with glm

```
# unweighted models

model_y_unweighted <- glm(
  formula = y_binary ~ m_binomial + pred_normal, 
  data = dat, 
  family = "binomial"
)

model_m_unweighted <- glm(
  formula = m_binomial ~ pred_normal, 
  data = dat, 
  family = "binomial",
  weights = m_binomial_max
)

mediation_unweighted <- mediation::mediate(
  model.m = model_m_unweighted,
  model.y = model_y_unweighted,
  treat = "pred_normal",
  mediator = "m_binomial",
  sims = 50
)

# Error in mediation::mediate(model.m = model_m_unweighted, model.y = model_y_unweighted, :
# weights on outcome and mediator models not identical
```

After checking the documentation, I see that you're not supposed to use a multiple-trial binomial mediator, as that is not implemented in the `mediation` package yet. My question is, why does it work when the models are fit through `survey::svyglm()`? And can I trust those results at all?